# Is this set a manifold?....

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x=cy, y\in M, c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\}$, where $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a manifold of dimension $d$. Note that $A$ determines the geometric shape that is always proportional to a shape determined by $M$, the scaling factor can be arbitrary. For example, if $M$ denotes the set of triangles with three prescribed edge lengths, then $A$ is the set of all triangles that are similar to triangles determined by $M$.

I think $A$ may have $d+1$ degrees of freedom since the geometric shape determined by $A$ can be magnified or reduced. I want to make sure that whether $A$ is a manifold of dimension $d+1$, how to prove it?

Comment: Hope someone could help me ......

Comment: I think your $A$ can fail to be regular whenever the radial vector is tangent to $M$. If you assume this never occurs, then $A$ is just the cone over the radial projection of $M$ on to a sphere, which will be a manifold.

Comment: Now assume there is a smooth map $f: X\rightarrow Y$, where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, $m<n$. If I can prove that each point in $A=f^{-1}(0)$ is regular, and $\max grad f=r$, can I conclude that $A$ is a manifold of dimension $n-r$? Is there any theorem we can employ? Please recommend some reference for me... Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, just view $X$ and $Y$ as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the regular value theorem.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It could help you to have a look at Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition. To be precise, look at Theorem 5.12 (Constant-Rank Level Set Theorem), Which I quote for convenience:

Comment: **Theorem 5.12 (Constant-Rank Level Set Theorem).** Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $\Phi \colon M \to N$ be a smooth map with constant rank $r$. Each level set of $\Phi$ is a properly embedded submanifold of codimension $r$ in M.

Comment: Thank you! Here the rank of $\Phi$ is $rank(grad \Phi)$?

Comment: Ok, I have found it from the reference you provided. You answer successfully solves my problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think $x=ca$ is not well-defined , so you could rather write 
$A =(\mathbb{R}\setminus0)\times M$ where you interpret the ordered pair $(c,m)$ as the object you originally wrote as $cm$.

Now observe, that $\mathbb{R}\setminus$ 0 and $M$ are manifolds and thus their cartesian product is too.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I missed that $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. The product of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $M$ is not a cartesian product. $cy$ is just a scalar multiplication, i.e., the product of a scalar $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$